# App force closes while open from recent used apps in google nexus

Tags: android

After use of my app i am pressing the Home to go app in background.here if i opened the app immediately again its opening the app.

But if i open the app after sometime means example 15 mins from recents its force closes the app with below logcat info

```
01-24 11:04:37.311: I/dalvikvm(6418): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
01-24 11:04:37.639: W/dalvikvm(6418): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c71930)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.roseenvy.ui.activities/com.roseenvy.ui.activities.AppHomeScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at com.roseenvy.ui.activities.AppHomeScreen.onCreate(AppHomeScreen.java:34)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at com.roseenvy.ui.fragments.Special.onCreateView(Special.java:42)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:846)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1061)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1160)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
01-24 11:04:37.654: E/AndroidRuntime(6418): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
```

This is only happening in my google nexus .I tested the app in LG optimus and google tab2 also on these  devices  app working without errors.

my activity layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pageflip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.roseenvy.ui.fragments.Special"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     />

    <fragment
        android:name="com.roseenvy.ui.fragments.CreateMyOwnViewPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/fragcreatehome"
      />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/previewfrag"
        android:name="com.roseenvy.ui.fragments.PreviewFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/addmessagefrag"
        android:name="com.roseenvy.ui.fragments.AddMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:name="com.roseenvy.ui.fragments.BuyNow"
        android:id="@+id/buynowfrag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:name="com.roseenvy.ui.fragments.ConfirmOrder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/confirmfrag"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

And this is my fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/i_spf_spl_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/specialLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/i_spf_transp_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/transp_logo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/spf_spl_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/this_weeks_special" />

            <com.roseenvy.ui.customviews.RoseTextView
                android:id="@+id/specialPrice"
                style="@style/SpecialText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/price_bkg"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

            <com.roseenvy.ui.customviews.RoseTextView
                android:id="@+id/specialTitle"
                style="@style/SpecialText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="50sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/gospecial"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <com.roseenvy.ui.customviews.RoseTextView
                    android:id="@+id/t_spf_spl_price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/see_special_offer"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="19sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/spl_offer_arrow" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/create_your_own" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/createownbottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="7dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/down_arrow" />

                <com.roseenvy.ui.customviews.RoseTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="@string/createyourown"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Activity Code

```
public class AppHomeScreen extends FragmentActivity {

    public static ViewFlipper pageFlip;

    private Utils utils;

    public AppPreferences appPreferences;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.apphome);
        pageFlip = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.pageflip);
        appPreferences = new AppPreferences(this);
        utils = new Utils();
    }
}
```

Fragment Code

```
public class Special extends BaseFragment implements OnClickListener {
    private ImageView specialBg;
    private RoseTextView title, price;
    public Bitmap bg;
    private LinearLayout createownbottom, gospecial;
    private SpecialProduct specialProduct;
    private String roseColor;
    public static boolean special = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.special_fragment, container, false);
        // pageFlip = AppHomeScreen.pageFlip;
        specialBg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.i_spf_spl_image);
        ImageDownloader imageLoader = new ImageDownloader(getActivity(), false);
        imageLoader.setMode(Mode.CORRECT);

        specialProduct = ApplicationData.getSpecialProduct();
        imageLoader.download(specialProduct.getSpecialImage(), specialBg, null);

        roseColor = specialProduct.getRoseInfo().getColor();
        title = (RoseTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.specialTitle);
        title.setText(specialProduct.getTitle().toUpperCase());
        price = (RoseTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.specialPrice);
        price.setText(getString(R.string._) + specialProduct.getPrice());
        price.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#" + roseColor));
        createownbottom = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.createownbottom);
        createownbottom.setOnClickListener(this);
        gospecial = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.gospecial);
        gospecial.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: As per your LogCat it seems your binary xml is not able to inflate..Can you post ur xml layout...

Comment: please check my layout code

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it seems that when you launch the app from Recents, it calls on a view which is no longer inflated as a result of the `Activity` being in the background for too long, and hence, killed.

The fact that this occurs on other devices and not on the Google Nexus doesn't really say much--when Android kills a background process can be arbitrary, depending on your memory usage and other factors. As in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle):

> The Android system attempts to keep application process around for as long as possible, but eventually will need to remove old processes when memory runs low. As described in Activity Lifecycle, the decision about which process to remove is intimately tied to the state of the user's interaction with it. In general, there are four states a process can be in based on the activities running in it, listed here in order of importance. The system will kill less important processes (the last ones) before it resorts to killing more important processes (the first ones).

Did you try to save the states of your app in the `onStop()` method, or re-inflate the components described in the above log in any of `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()`, or `onRestart()`? It's really up to you which of those methods you'll use. For reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle